# Jquery run code and show results to console after form is submited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run code once form is submitted, but when I press the button it navigates me to another page (index.html?) and there is no result in console, what am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input1").submit(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var lim = $("#input1").val();
    for (var i = 1; i < lim; i++) {
      if ((i % 3) == 0 || (i % 5) == 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    console.log(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="input1">
  <input type="text" value="1000" class="inputText">
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to do with `sum` variable? What you describe is expected behaviour

Comment: @A. Wolff it should be incremented by one everytime condition (i%3)==0 || (i%5)==0 is met and the be printed out in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that the selected answer is entirely correct.

The only apparent problem with OP's code is in using the wrong element ID. The calculation was based on the value of "#input2", yet OP's code incorrectly used "#input1". Obviously that will break the calculation output to the console.

Inserting e.preventDefault(); in the code does not appear to be part of the solution. jQuery will complete the calculation before submitting the form. Tested this by adding a long calculation and it worked okay. And since there are no asynchronous calls used (causing a race condition) it seems safe to just let the form submit normally.

*(Note: Either *e.preventDefault();* or *return false;* will both prevent form submission.)*

One issue that wasn't addressed is that some debuggers clear the console on navigation. For example, console persistence is an option that can be switched on in Chrome. And this would need to be enable to see the console output after form submit.

Answer (score 2):

You need prevent default action of form submit, for that use **[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** and also you are not specified id to element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sum = 0;
    var lim = $("#input2").val();
    for (var i = 1; i < lim; i++) {
      if ((i % 3) == 0 || (i % 5) == 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    console.log(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2" value="1000" class="inputText">
  <!-- set id here ---^---------------------------------------->
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think there is problem with getting value of the text field, because it returns 0 every time.

Answer (score 0):

> when you have form, there must be a method of "GET" or "POST". Coming
>   to your question it returns me sum as 0.

```
console.log(sum) = 0
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8kzf0wdf/